# Raise exception upon statement in python

Tags: python

I'm new to python, and i want to make a simple bank account class, where i want to make a withdraw method, that checks if founds are sufficient and then raises an exception if not.

```
   def withdraw(self, amount):
        self.amount -= amount
        if amount < self.amount:
            raise Exception("Insufficent founds")
        print(f"{amount} was withdrawn new balance is {self.amount}")
```

this is what i have so far, and the logic is working, but i think it would be better with a

```
try:
    # method logic
except Exception:
    #handle exception and continue program
```

my issue is that i can't trigger the exception upon a statement like:

```
  if amount < self.amount:
```

what do you do in python, when you want to throw an exception upon a certain event, and then continue the program?

Comment: *Within* that function? You don't - either you want to throw an error and end the function execution, or not throw an error at all.

Comment: okay but, what if i want to prompt a message, that there is insufficent founds, and just break out of the function?

Comment: Your code is bugged. You are reducing the balance *before* checking if you have sufficient funds. PS it's "funds" not "founds".

Comment: I don't understand the question. You say the function works fine. Then you say the code would be better with a `try...except`. I don't see what's preventing you from adding said `try...except`? I also can't make sense of "you want to throw an exception upon a certain event, and then continue the program". Continue the program from where?

Comment: Throw the error. It's up to the *caller* to handle it, or let it bubble up, but there's absolutely no point throwing an error inside a `try` block that's only there to catch it.

Comment: @Aran-Fey so the execution does not stop, upon an exception, basiclly the exception is handled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of an exception is for a function to indicate *to its caller* that it was unable to do whatever thing it is intended to do.

So if you have a function called `withdraw`, and its purpose is to withdraw funds, if for any reason it cannot withdraw funds, it is appropriate for that function to raise an exception.

If the function identifies a situation where it *might* be able to withdraw funds, and it performs some extra steps (like prompting the user) and then succeeds, there is no need for any exception. The function still did what it was intended to do. Having the `withdraw` function take on an extra responsibility of asking for approval seems like a poor design to me, though.

One way to help understand what exceptions you need to raise is to work *top down* instead of *bottom up*. That is, start by writing the highest level of what you want your program to do, and then work your way down to the specific details.

If your goal is to simulate an ATM machine, for example, you might start with a top-level function like this:

```
def main():
    while running:
        account = select_account()
        operation = select_operation()

        if operation == 'withdraw':
            amount = select_amount()
            try:
                account.withdraw(amount)
            except InsufficientFundsError:
                print('Your account has insufficient funds.')

        elif operation == 'deposit':
            amount = select_amount()
            account.deposit(amount) 

        elif operation == 'done':
            running = False
```

If you start with this "client" code that will use your class, it makes the design for the "service" code (your `Account` class) much easier. Now you know how you want to be able to use your object, so it's just a matter of writing an object that can be used that way.

When you write a call to a function like `account.withdraw(amount)`, you need to think: How could this fail? What do I want to do if it fails? For example, if the failure reason is that there are insufficient funds, you want to print a message, but you probably don't want to abort the program. But if when you call `select_account()` the account doesn't exist, then maybe it's OK to fail in a different way. If you fail to handle a possible exception, then the default thing that happens is that your program crashes. That's a good thing: it means that you've found some code that you forgot to write, and if that happens, it's much better for your program to stop running completely than to continue on doing the wrong thing.

Comment: This answer is more complete than mine, real neat way of coding!

Answer (score 0):

A try/except only gets specific errors in python and prevents crashes so the program can keep running (or not if you break). If you don't specify a python's exception it will treat any exception it occurs.

```
try:
    # something
except:
    pass #(do nothing)
```

However if you wan't to treat only specific errors, meaning to catch/ignore only it but others will have other treatments (or even crash on screen) you specify:

```
div = 0

try:
    print(10/div)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("div can't be zero, change variable")
    return # this exits the function
    #break # if it is inside a loop
```

Basically, ***when you treat an exception the program doesn't stop, it just act like a "known bug" so doesn't crash.***

what you could do is exit the function inside your if, but you'd have to do that check before the operation:

```
def withdraw(self, amount):

    if amount < self.amount:
        print("Insufficent funds")
        return

    self.amount -= amount
    print(f"{amount} was withdrawn new balance is {self.amount}")
```

An edit: ***a better approach*** would be instead of printing the "insuficient funds" to ***either write into a log file or returning an output to the program*** calling this class/function.

Comment: This is not a good solution. You're misusing break. Even if you change that to 'return', the caller of your withdraw function has no clue that there was a problem.

Comment: Oh, was thinking on a loop when I typed that, `replaced` the `break` for `return, thanks. But it did solve his problem as his final sentence and question was `what do you do in python, when you want to throw an exception upon a certain event, and then continue the program?`. So, you see... he want to keep running the program. A better solution would be write a log file, but that deviates from the question.

Comment: This is not how error handling is done. The withdraw method needs to return an indication of insufficient funds, whether that is done through a return code or done through an exception. The *caller* of the withdraw function is then responsible for handling the error.

Comment: that is not an error handling that is a custom condition He set... The way you described ***might*** be your view of tackling a problem/coding, but not specifically The way. Do you by any chance have a PEP page proving your point so I could change my view/answer completely?